# Opposite something

Tags: sentence, word-order

What is the right possibility ?

1. I am opposite the wall
2. I am opposite to the wall
3. I am in the opposite to the wall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to be opposite an object in the physical sense, there has to be something between you, and your face has to be looking toward a face of the object, at least figuratively.

The word *opposite* comes from the Latin *oppono*, but it appears in various forms in the European languages that Latin has influenced. The [Wiktionary entry](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/opposite) seems to lead in all directions.

To my ears, the first sentence sounds more natural, but so long as the core sense of *opposition* from the original Latin is maintained, you could probably use any number of prepositions to convey additional meaning.